# Add Error on GET METHOD Spring annotated controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

I have this scenario:

1. I display a list of assets to users.
2. User selects an asset and then clicks add item
3. On my requestmapping, during GET operation.  I use the service class to check if indeed this asset still exist in DB
4. If not, user should be notified by a message.  I use the form:error tag

My problem is when I add the error object in the method signature, I got this error:

> Errors/BindingResult argument declared without preceding model attribute

Code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addItemsToAsset.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String setupForm(@RequestParam("assetID") Long assetID,
            Errors error, ModelMap model) {
        AssetItemVo voAsset = null;

        if (assetID != null && assetID != 0) {
            //Get data for asset from DB using assetID
            List<AssetDraftTempVo> lstDraft = service.getAssetDraftByLngID(assetID);

            if (lstDraft.size() == 0) {
                voAsset = new AssetItemVo();
                // I wanted to add validation here.  If no data for asset id is found, I would like to add an error to the error object
                error.reject("123","Unable to find info for the asset in the database.");
            } else {
                AssetDraftTempVo voDraft = lstDraft.get(0);
                voAsset = new AssetItemVo();
                voAsset.setStrPlant(voDraft.getStrPlant());
                .
                . /*other DTO property here*/
                .
            }
        }
        model.put("assetItemDetail", voAsset);
        return "additemstoasset";
    }
```

My goal is that during the display of the form, I wanted to populate the error object right away (if there is an error)

Here's my form for clarity.

```
<form:form modelAttribute="assetItemDetail"  method="post">
    <div id="error_paragraph">
        <form:errors path="*" cssClass="errors" />
    </div>
</form:form>
```

To get past the error, I manually change the method signature and added the model attribute but it still cannot populate the form:error tag

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addItemsToAsset.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String setupForm(@RequestParam("assetID") Long assetID,
        @ModelAttribute("assetItemDetail") AssetItemVo voAssetData, Errors error,
        ModelMap model)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to associate a `BindingResult` with a model attribute that doesn't present in the method signature, you can do it manually:

```
BindingResult result = new Errors();
...
model.put(BindingResult.MODEL_KEY_PREFIX + "assetItemDetail", result); 
model.put("assetItemDetail", voAsset);
```

Answer (score 3):

Spring MVC needs to associate a bunch of errors with some objects on the model, so tags such as `<form:errors path="..." />` will correspond to model objects according to the `path` attribute.  In this case, it does so by looking for the `Errors` argument directly after the `ModelMap` argument in your controller method.

Try swapping the error and model method arguments and see if it clears up the "Errors/BindingResult argument declared without preceding model attribute" error.

Change this:

```
public String setupForm(@RequestParam("assetID") Long assetID,
        @ModelAttribute("assetItemDetail") AssetItemVo voAssetData, Errors error,
        ModelMap model)
```

to this:

```
public String setupForm(@RequestParam("assetID") Long assetID,
        @ModelAttribute("assetItemDetail") AssetItemVo voAssetData, ModelMap model,
        Errors error)
```